# Unity POST request to local host

Tags: python, c#, http, unity-game-engine, post

Soooooo, I've checked every answer I can on this site. But I'm not finding a solution that is working. I'm trying to log a user into a site I am developing on local host from a unity application. I'm not passing the boolean "remember" because it was giving me issues.

My unity code is:

```
    IEnumerator Login(string username, string password, bool remember)
    {
        List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
        formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("username=" + username + "&password=" + password));

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/children/mobile_login/", formData))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            var response = www.downloadHandler.text;

            Debug.Log(response);

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Login complete!");
            }
        }
    }
```

and my python code is:

```
@children.route('/mobile_login', methods=['POST'])
def mobile_login():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    remember = request.form.get('remember')
    user = User.objects(username=username).first()
    if user and crypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
        login_user(user)
        user.save()
        token = user.get_auth_token()
        res = make_response(jsonify({"user": user}), 200)
        if remember:
            res.set_cookie('child-auth', value=token, path='/')
        return res
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "unable to login"}), 401
```

The code is returning  "{"error": "unable to login"}" and HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.

I know for a fact that the username and password are correct. And I know the log in function works because my colleague is able to login from the react app he is working on.

I tried running my local host as https but that didn't work so I changed it back to http.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using a `WWWForm` like `var form = new WWWForm(); form.AddField("username", username); form.AddField("password", password);`? Are you also sure they are received correctly? Maybe encoding is an issue?

Comment: Just tracing through the server side of things, one of your login conditions must be false, either `user` is a `None` or otherwise evaluates to `False`, or your `check_password_hash` fails to verify the hash of your password. Using debugging tools on the server side could probably show what is being passed for the password, and it might be beneficial to see if there are any extra characters being prepended or appended, or if the encoding is different.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first response between python and C#.  Also check the TLS version.  The python code isn't showing the IP address so see if python is using the loopback 127.0.0.1 or something else.  HTTPS uses TLS as the authentication and the version of TLS may be different.  Check sniffer to see if python and c# are using same version of TLS.